# How do I prove (or disprove) $A-(B-C) = (A-B) \cup (A \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have tested the relation through letting A, B, C be $\phi$ and determined that the identity holds.

My steps so far:

Assume $x \in A-(B-C) \rightarrow \ $
$x \in A \ and \ x \notin (B-C) \rightarrow \ $
$x \in A \ and \ x \notin B \ and \ x \in C$

I am unsure about what to do next (also is $x \in C$? I figured since a double negative would make it so that it is an element of C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \in A-(B-C) \iff x \in A \land x\notin (B-C)$

Now:

$x\notin (B-C)\implies \neg x \in (B-C)$.

So:

$\neg (x\in B \land x \notin C)$

Implying:

$x\notin B\lor x \in C$

by rules of first order logic.

Hence we have:

$x \in A \land (x\notin B \lor x \in C)$

Implying:
$x\in (A-B)\cup (A\cap C)$

Answer (score 0):

If you know De Morgan law, you can write it a bit more quickly as follows

\begin{align}
 A - (B - C) &= A - (B\cap C^c) = A\cap (B\cap C^c)^c \\
&= A\cap(B^c\cup C) \quad (\text{De Morgan law}) \\
&= (A\cap B^c) \cup(A\cap C) \quad (\text{Distributive law})
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You have an error where you move from $ x \notin B - C $ to $ x \notin B \; \wedge \; x \notin C $ (where $ \wedge $ here is the logical AND operator).  Since $ x \in B - C $ means $ x \in B \; \wedge \; x \notin C $, you have $ x \notin B - C \; \longleftrightarrow \; \neg ( x \in B \; \wedge \; x \notin C ) $ (where $ \neg $ here is the logical NOT operator).  But remember that $ \neg ( P \wedge Q ) $ is equivalent to $ \neg P \vee \neg Q $ (where $ \vee $ here is the logical OR operator), not to $ \neg P \wedge \neg Q $.  So $ x \notin B - C \; \longleftrightarrow \; x \notin B \; \vee \; x \in C $, not $ x \notin B \; \wedge \; x \notin C $ as you said.  (You are correct that the negation of $ x \notin C $ is simply $ x \in C $, in classical logic.)

So with this correction, you can continue as you were going:  $$ x \in A - ( B - C ) \; \longrightarrow \; x \in A \; \wedge \; x \notin B - C \; \longrightarrow \; x \in A \; \wedge \; ( x \notin B \; \vee \; x \in C ) \; \longrightarrow \; \cdots \text . $$  The next step is to distribute the AND over OR.  However, this only proves one direction, so you should probably write $ \longleftrightarrow $ instead of $ \rightarrow $ between each step.  (This means checking that each step is reversible, but they are; they use only definitions and logical equivalences.)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake when you replaced $x \notin (B - C)$ with $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$.

$x \notin (B - C)$ would mean $x \notin B$ or $x \in C$.

So here's I would go about it.

$$\begin{align*} 
&x \in A - (B - C) \\[0.075cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,&x \in A \,\,\text{ and }\,\, x \notin(B - C) \\[0.075cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,&x \in A \,\,\text{ and }\,\, (x \notin B \,\text{ or }\, x \in C) \\[0.075cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,&x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B \,\,\,\text{ or } \,\,\, x \in A \text{ and } x \in C \\[0.075cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,&x \in (A - B) \,\,\, \text{or} \,\,\, x \in (A \cap C) \\[0.075cm]
\Longleftrightarrow \,\,&x \in (A - B) \cup (A \cap C) \\[0.075cm]
\end{align*}$$

Hence proved.